# Unknown source (unknown package/class) causing null point exception on a few users

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-drive-api

I have this app, with almost 300 users but sometimes I get this crash report. If the App tries to Sync with the user's Google Drive, it just closes and show the "The App Closed" pop-up with the Report and OK buttons. It happens after some time using the app without any problem.

The crash reports on the dev console are the same:

> 

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mydomain.myappname.b.a(Unknown Source)
at com.mydomain.myappname.b.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
... 5 more
```

I checked the com.mydomain.myappname.b.a proguard/mappings.txt and added the class to the proguard-project.txt to keep it not obfuscated. The problem persists but now it shows a different class on the mappings.txt file. So I believe obfuscation is not the problem.

It has already happened on 3 different devices, all of them running Android 4.1 (API 16) according to Developer Console. But, I've just tested my app on a 4.1.2 device and it works fine.

I've also checked my code for any doInBackground() and all of them catch generic exceptions. So I believe it should catch it and not crash, right?

I can't reproduce the error on my devices.

I have no idea where to look for this problem.

Any clue?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the implementation of doInBackground()?

Comment: I don't know which AsyncTask this doInBackground() belongs to. And all of them are very big. Plus, all of them have try / catch blocks for general Exceptions, so I believe any exception would be caught and don't close the app. That's why I don't understand this log.